# Использовать чистый OpenGL или Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Есть не большой опыт работы с OpenGL для создания двумерных сцен. Сейчас решил поработать с 3D и встал такой вопрос: **как лучше?**

1) Использовать чистый OpenGL?

2) Работать с OpenGL через Qt?
Логика подсказывает, что этот вариант должен быть более предпочтительней и проще,но только дело в том, что по чистому OpenGL куча туториалов, а вот по OpenGL ES в Qt их нет, по крайней мере на русском.

**Основная цель** - получение реального опыта работы с графикой. 
И по сути такие вопросы сформировались:

1) Какой из вариантов используется в реальном геймдеве (когда компания свой движок изначально пишет, к примеру)?

2) Какой из вариантов будет более предпочтителен для работодателя? Если у меня есть опыт с чистым OpenGL или череез обертки Qt?

Answer (score 2):

С Opengl проще работать без qt , но qt поможет если вы будете делать кроссплатформенное приложение .
Так что тут выбор между скоростью разработки и портабельностью проекта в дальнейшем.
P.s я использую чистый OpenGL в связке с GLSL.